# VS2022-ngrok tunnel: could not find ngrok download url

Tags: visual-studio-2022, ngrok

I cannot start ngrok tunnel in Visual Studio 2022.

When I click on start ngrok tunnel, it gives me:

[image: first prompt]

Then after clicking yes, it gives me:

[image: error]

I have done everything I could:

- Added .exe path to environment variable
- Added .exe path under ngrok tree in vs 2022

Any help would be appreciated!